# Cassandra - Reinserting deleted column

Tags: cassandra, pelops

I was just running few simple tests (inserts and deletes) on column family I created. 
I observed that while new columns are getting inserted against a row key, but  a column that has been recently deleted, does not get inserted.

For example:

rowkey1 :: name1-val1 
                 name2-val2
After deleting name1, if I try to insert it again I still get

rowkey1 ::  name2-val2 and does not revert back to name1-val1, name2-val2.

The problem occurs when I try to insert it through my code (using Pelops Java client)
Following is the code snippet that I use for insertion:

```
            Mutator mutator = Pelops.createMutator("poolname");
            Column column = new Column(bufcolname);
            column.setValue(bufcolval);
            column.setTimestamp(new Date().getTime());
            mutator.writeColumn("MyColumnFamily",userId, column);
            mutator.execute(ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
```

Thanks

Comment: How many nodes are there for this column family and how soon after the delete are you trying to insert the new columns?

Comment: Hi Chris, There are 2 nodes and I tried inserting it say after 2-5 minutes. Both the nodes are running on the same machine.  BTW this is what fixed the problem.: I changed my code to `List<Column> colList = new ArrayList<Column>();
   for (...) {
    
    colList.add(mutator.newColumn(keyname, keyval));
    
   }
   mutator.writeColumns(COLFAMILY, userId, colList);`

Answer (score 5):

Most likely this is a timestamp issue.

If writes conflict, cassandra uses timestamps to decide the winner.  In the code above, you are setting the timestamp using milliseconds, but by convention, cassandra uses timestamps in [micro seconds](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DataModel).

> Timestamps can be anything you like, but microseconds since 1970 is a convention.

So your delete is probably using a timestamp of micro seconds, which is > than the ms timestamp for your add, hence the add will always be shadowed by the delete.